# How to get base64 from input file in IE without using FileReader or HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, html4

I hope I can have help from you. I need to get a file from an HTML `input` file element.

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="allegatoImg" id="allegatoImg" onchange="javascript:readURL(this)"/>
```

And this is JavaScript:

```
function readURL(input) {
    var mimeType;
    if (window.FileReader) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var dataURL = e.target.result;
                mimeType = dataURL.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];
                if (mimeType == 'image/jpeg') {
                    jQuery('#imgallegato').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    //jQuery('#fotoTemp').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    provaInvioImgSrcToServer();
                } else {
                    alert('Errore nella lettura del file. Controllare che sia stato caricato un file con estensione jpeg.');
                    return;
                }
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    } else {
        f = document.dettRichAbbForm;
        document.getElementById("imgallegato").src = "file:///" + input.value;
        var estensione = ctrlExtensionFileIE(input.value);
        alert('path file = ' + jQuery("#imgallegato").attr('src') );

        if (estensione=='jpg' || estensione=='jpeg') {
            provaInvioImgSrcToServer();
        } else {
            alert('Error in reading file');
            return;
        }
    }
}

function provaInvioImgSrcToServer() {
    var urlToCall = provaInvioImgSrcToServerUrl;
    alert('img path = ' + jQuery("#imgallegato").attr('src'));

    jQuery.ajax({
        cache   : false,
        type    : "POST",
        timeout : 5000,
        url     : urlToCall,
        data    : {imgSource: jQuery("#imgallegato").attr('src')},
        success : function(result) {                    
            ritagliaImg();
        },
        error : function(errorMsg) {
            //gestAjaxCallError(errorMsg, divResultBodId, divResultBodId);
            alert('Errore nel caricamento dell\'immagine selezionata.');
        }
    });
}

function ctrlExtensionFileIE(value) {
    var splittedVal = value.split(".");
    return splittedVal[1];
}
```

I'm working on *Liferay 5.1* with an old version of *jQuery* so I can't use HTML5 with canvas element, because I should load the image from the input file into a *Jcrop* element.

My problem is linked to this part of the code:

```
f = document.dettRichAbbForm;                       
document.getElementById("imgallegato").src = "file:///" + input.value;
```

*FileReader* works fine in Mozilla, Chrome and IE10+, but with IE9- I should use the code above.
The problem is that `input.value` returns the path of the selected file and **I need to get the base64** in order to send it to the server. I can't do the submit of my form, because this approach needs to re-load my jsp and I have others fields.

Is there someone that could help me to get the byte array from selected file on IE without using canvas element, HTML5 and FileReader library?

Comment: https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't use flash in my work, I need to use only javascript and jquery. Company policies...

Comment: I don't know anything about ActiveX, but try searching something... In my projects when there is no FileReader native support, we just remove this feature and patch it with simple file upload or asking for an URL to the image. You can't get blood out of a stone.

Comment: You are right, I'll try in other way. Thanks for your reply.